# Gauss elimination function fails when I try to get the implicit equations of a variety

Tags: python, matrix, typeerror, sympy, gaussian

GOAL: What I'm trying to do is to get the implicit equations of a variety, which is given by a points and its spanning vectors. Well, you know, you must the Gaussian elimination of the matrix of these spanning vector with a column of variables (x1,..., xn) minus the point. By the way, I'm using sympy.

So, I've implemented a beautiful Gauss elimination function, which works perfectly well with normal matrices (I mean, just with numbers, without X's):

```
def gauss(matrix):
rows,columns = matrix.shape
n = min(rows,columns)
a = matrix[:,:]
for i in range(n-1):
    k = i
    for j in range(i + 1, rows):
        if abs(a[j,i]) > abs(a[k,i]):
            k = j

    if k != i:
        a[i,:], a[k,:] = a[k,:], a[i,:]

    for j in range(i + 1 , rows):
        t = a[j,i]/a[i,i]
        a[j,i:] -= t*a[i,i:]
return a
```

And then I tried to use this function upon my matrix of the spanning vectors with X's-point like that:

```
point = sympy.Matrix([-1,-3,0,5,3])
generators = sympy.Matrix([[0,0,3,3,0],[-1,4,-3,3,-1],[1,4,-4,-5,-1],[0,8,0,5,-2]]).T
m, n = generators.shape
var_list = sympy.Matrix(variables[:m])
vars = var_list-point
M = generators.col_insert(n, vars)
gauss(M)
```

TROUBLE: And on the last line I get this message:

```
TypeError: cannot add <class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'> and <class 'sympy.core.numbers.NaN'>
```

I think it's something with the "minus point" stuff because when I try this Gauss function on matrix with numbers and a column of variables it works perfectly well.

So I can't find what's wrong and I don't understand the error. Would be very grateful if anybody helped me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `generators` matrix is column-deficient, its rank is less than the number of columns. `gauss(generators)` returns

```
Matrix([
[3, -3,   -4,    0],
[0,  6,   -1,    5],
[0,  0, 14/3, 14/3],
[0,  0,    0,    0],
[0,  0,    0,    0]])
```

with zero pivot in the last column. This does not cause errors in your `gauss` function because it does not deal with the 4th column, it being the last column.

But when one more column is added to the matrix, it will now process the 4th column. This will cause 0/0 division, resulting in NaN, and an error at a subsequent attempt to add NaN to a number. This is what the matrix looks like just before the fatal step.

```
Matrix([
[3, -3,   -4,    0,                                     x2],
[0,  6,   -1,    5,                           -x2 + x3 - 5],
[0,  0, 14/3, 14/3,            x1 + 2*x2/3 - 2*x3/3 + 19/3],
[0,  0,    0,    0, x0 - 5*x1/28 - 2*x2/7 + 2*x3/7 - 27/28],
[0,  0,    0,    0,                        x1/4 + x4 - 9/4]])
```

By the way, the conditional statement

```
    if abs(a[j,i]) > abs(a[k,i]):
        k = j
```

would itself throw an error if `a[j, i]` or `a[k, i]` contained symbols (because it is unknown whether the inequality holds or not). This does not happen because your symbols are all in the last column.

#### Better approach

Since your variety (affine subspace) has dimension 3 and there are 5 variables, it is described by two implicit equations. You can get their coefficients from the nullspace of the transpose of the generator matrix (assuming coefficients are real, otherwise we need Hermitian transpose `.H`).  This is because the coefficients of implicit equations come from a basis of orthogonal complement, which is what the nullspace of transpose gives.

```
import sympy 
point = sympy.Matrix([-1,-3,0,5,3])
generators = sympy.Matrix([[0,0,3,3,0],[-1,4,-3,3,-1],[1,4,-4,-5,-1],[0,8,0,5,-2]]).T
m, n = generators.shape
variables = sympy.symbols('x0:{}'.format(m))
var_list = sympy.Matrix(variables)
vars = var_list-point
coeffs = generators.T.nullspace()
for c in coeffs:
    print((c.T*vars)[0])
```

This prints two equations (with `= 0` understood.)

```
7*x0/2 - 5*x1/8 - x2 + x3 - 27/8
x1/4 + x4 - 9/4
```